# Hide/Show multiple series in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using HighCharts. I have data that is rendered in a pie chart. When I click on the legend-label, I can hide/show my different pie slices. Woo!

What I would like to do, is hide/show different columns to the same effect in this view. (Clicking on dog/bird should remove the column - the same as the pie slice).

My series is:

```
    series: [{
        type: "pie", //Change to "column"
        data:[{
            name: "dog",
            age: 52,
            y: 52
        },
        {
            name: "bird",
            age: 12,
            y: 12
        }]
    }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lmbw75mg/

How can I change my structure so that it will work for both?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want two legend items just by changed "pie" to "column", that can toggle the individual columns? I'm fairly certain the outcome here wont be to have the same code, and have it working in both cases, but maybe similar functionality with different code.

Comment: Which column do you mean? Do you mean instead of `type: 'pie'` you want `type: 'column'`? So in this [column demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-allowpointselect-column/) a click on month `May` would hide the box for may?

Comment: You mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmbw75mg/1/?

Comment: Or a better one like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmbw75mg/2/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making it the same in a column chart you'll have to use two series, not one:

```
series: [{
        type: "column",
        name: "dog",
        data: [{
            age: 52,
            x: 0,
            y: 52
        }]
    }, {
        type: "column",
        name: "bird",
        data: [{
            age: 12,
            x: 1,
            y: 12
        }]
    }]
```

Also you'll have to define **`categories`** for xAxis:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    tickWidth: 0,
    lineColor: "#C0D0E0",
    lineWidth: 1,
    categories: ['dog', 'bird']
}
```

And for making the columns equally spaced, you'll need to set **`plotOptions.column.grouping`** to false:

```
plotOptions: {
    colorByPoint: true,
    column: {
        grouping: false
    }
}
```

Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmbw75mg/2/).

Comment: So the answer is that I cannot simply just switch "column" to "pie" and be able to hide/show series. Legend entries are based on "series", not on data points.

Comment: Yes, column chart differs from pie chart in this part. you can add multiple data to one series in pie, but you'll have to add multiple series for column.